# Are Subversion 1.6 & Xcode 3.2 compatible?

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode, macos, version-control

Trying to get Xcode to work with Subversion server.

- Server: Subversion upgraded to 1.6.9 (Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.8)
- Client: Xcode 3.2.1 (Snow Leopard 10.6.2 with
  Subversion 1.6.5 though not sure that matters)

Repository on server is setup and working fine via command line.

However, I get an error when trying to create the Repository connection in Xcode:

```
Error: 160043 (Unsupported FS format) Description: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'
```

a Google search seems to say that the server needs to be updated...but it's running 1.6.9 which is the most current version I'm aware of.

Anyone know how to make this work? **Is it even possible?**

*I'm well aware of the command line usage but I would like to get Xcode & SVN talking...*

**Revisiting this after some time:**

Using command line: `username$ svn+ssh://hostname/Library/Subversion/Repository/test`

yields the same result: `Description: Expected FS format '2'; found format`

Can anyone verify that I need to upgrade Subversion on the client machine to match version on server (1.6.9)?!? was hoping i wouldn't have to unless it was a "major" revision (ie. 1.5.x -> 1.6.x)

Comment: any ideas? still struggling with this `Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'` error!! very annoying! i'm guessing it has something to do with the default install of Subversion in Mac OS X Server but which svn points to the updated one in `/opt/subversion/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before on OSX Server 10.5 as the SVN server.  On our server, /usr/bin/svn is version 1.4.4.  The version of SVN we actually use is 1.6.9 from Fink.  We needed to make sure that /sw/bin was in the path before /usr/bin... I think I solved this by having sh /sw/bin/init.sh in my .profile AND symlinking .profile to .bashrc or bash_profile so it would be loaded by svn+ssh.

Comment: I'm using Collabnet's update to Subversion. I put the update into /opt/ instead of /sw/ and added export PATH="/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH" to .profile to an account running on the server. still getting `svn: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'` errors.